# Typescript call signature error for exported async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await

I have a Typescript file (**colorTheme.ts**) that looks like this:

```
export default (async (key) => {
  console.log(key)
  const themeImport = await import(`../build/theme/${key}/color.js`)
  return themeImport
})()
```

And then I reference this function from a separate Typescript file like so:

```
import colorTheme from '../colorTheme'

colorTheme('test').then(color => {
  // do stuff
})
```

However, I get an error:

> TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Promise' has no compatible call signatures.

I've googled around and tried things like:

```
export default (async (key: string) => {
  console.log(key)
  const themeImport = await import(`../build/theme/${key}/color.js`)
  return themeImport
})()
```

But to no avail. Typescript isn't my forte, it's a preexisting environment that I'm trying to work in. From what I understand I need to somehow setup types for the Promise maybe? But I'm not sure how to do that.

*Update: Added a bit more fuller code sample for what I'm trying to do.*

Comment: What you are trying to do here using an **IIFE** is to export a `Promise`. Because you are executing an `async` function and returns it *(an async function returns a Promise)*. What are you trying to do ? I don't think that returning a `Promise` is something viable importing a file

Comment: Updated the code examples with a little more context.

Comment: `const themeImport = await import(\`../build/theme/${key}/color.js\`)` eeeuh I'm not sure it will ever work. Unless `import` is not a regular import, such code will be transpiled, so you won't be able to resolve the import at runtime on the compiled code. Also, the self invoking anonymous function will never get the `key` argument. Is there any reason to use an IIFE here?..

Comment: It works if I pass in the key value manually (e.g. `async() => { const key = 'test' ...`). It's the ability to be able to pass dynamic keys via the function call that seems to be giving me the problem.

Comment: Of course if you declare it it will work, the question is why you're using an IIFE. It's overcomplicated, you just need to export a **function** that should return a **promise**. IIFE are not meant to be used in this way, keep in mind that the above code will be executed **immediately** due to the nature of IIFE, I don't think this is what you want ;)

Comment: You cannot perform asynchronous `import`. `import` must ba ll about synchronous stuff. What you can do is returning a SINGLETON class and then call the initiation

Comment: Thanks all, the problem is the **IIFE** I see now. I've removed it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a look at the two trailing parenthesis:

```
(async (x) => {
  console.log(x)
})() <--
```

You are executing the function as you declare it. This is a so-called `IIFE`: *Immediately Invoked Function Expression*.

Let's split the export adding a variable:

```
const result = (async (x) => {
  console.log(x)
})();

export default result;
```

What's the value of result? Well, the value of result is equal to the return value of the function. If it was a normal function, this was equal to a function immediately resolved as `undefined`. Since it is an async function and we aren't returning anything, this means that the returned value is a `Promise` of `undefined`.

So what you are exporting is an already resolved promise! But... what about the parameter x?

Well, the function accepts a parameter `x`, but you are actually passing nothing. Watch again the trailing parenthesis, there is nothing inside, so you will see `undefined` in the console if you execute the code.

If instead you passed an argument, for example a string, you saw that string:

```
(async (x) => {
  console.log(x) // It prints banana!
})('banana')
```

So here is the point where you have to pass the argument, then the function gets immediately invoked and the result is exported.

Let's rewrite `colorTheme.ts` in a simpler way:

### 1. Add a variable

```
const result = (async (x) => {
  console.log(x)
})();

export default result;
```

### 2. Return `undefined` (it's the same of not returning)

```
const result = (async (x) => {
  console.log(x)
  return undefined;
})();

export default result;
```

### 3. Use `Promise` in place of `async`

```
const result = (x => {
  console.log(x)
  return Promise.resolve(undefined);
})();

export default result;
```

### 4. Don't invoke the function immediately

```
const f = function (x) {
  console.log(x)
  return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}

const result = f(undefined);

export default result;
```

So, this is basically what you exported. Now it ups to you to fix it according to what you want to get!

Comment: Ahh okay, this makes sense now. Thank you for the detailed reply!

Comment: I added more details. I made everything explicit, since many things are often implicit and someone could not know them